# Recursively generate combinations of numbers

Tags: c++, recursion, logic, combinations, permutation

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve with a recursive algorithm of some sort (using C++).

Say you're given two arrays: [0x10, 0x01] and [2, 4].

The result that the algorithm should return is all combinations of the two bitmasks, where each bitmask's non zero part can be any value from 0 to its corresponding value in the second array.

For example, for the above arrays I would have to generate an array (or vector) containing the values:

```
0x00 (both bitmasks are 0)
0x01 (first bitmask is 0, second is 1)
0x02 (first bitmask is 0, second is 2)
0x03 (first bitmask is 0, second is 3)
0x10 (first bitmask is 1, second is 0)
0x11 (first bitmask is 1, second is 1)
0x12 (first bitmask is 1, second is 2)
0x13 (first bitmask is 1, second is 3).
```

In case that explanation didn't make sense, another example with the following two arrays:
[0x100, 0x010, 0x001] and [2, 3, 2] would result in the values:

```
0x000
0x001
0x010
0x011
0x020
0x021
0x100
0x101
0x110
0x111
0x120
0x121
```

I'm trying to make a recursive algorithm that takes in these two arrays and will output all the possible combinations in an array or vector but can't quite figure out the algorithm. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to have a recursive algorithm with a loop counter array that counts the number of times I've looped through a certain bitmask index but still could not finish off the algorithm.

Comment: This isn't a school question - it's a problem I'm encountering in a project and am trying to work through it. I've tried drafting solutions on paper but just can't seem to get the algorithm down.

Comment: The examples don't really help.   For example, given that both examples involve non-zero input arrays, it's not clear to me how - logically - the first has output with both bitmasks zero while the second does not.

Comment: @Peter Forgot to add the 0x00 for the second example

Comment: Is the first array really useful? i seems you just do Cartesian product of the second array.

Comment: Why recursive, while iteration seem more natural?

Comment: Maybe [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) could be of use?

Answer (score 1):

###### Using a `cartesian_product_iterator` to generate Cartesian products

A couple of decades ago, I worked out the "odometer" logic for the `cartesian_product_iterator` defined below. It is not a real iterator, but it behaves enough like one to deserve the name. No recursion is necessary.

Using a `cartesian_product_iterator` is relatively straightforward.

```cpp
tbx::cartesian_product_iterator cpi{ 2, 4 }; // construct from std::initializer_list
for (; !cpi.is_at_end(); ++cpi)              // loop until the iterator is at its end
    std::cout << cpi << '\n';                // operator<< is overloaded for 
                                             //   cartesian_product_iterator
```

The code above produces the following output :

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
```

Dereferencing a `cartesian_product_iterator` returns an object of type `std::vector<int>`. After construction, for instance, `cpi` is internally initialized to a vector of zeros. Dereferencing `cpi` returns that vector.

```cpp
tbx::cartesian_product_iterator cpi{ 2, 3, 2 };
std::vector<int> v{ 0, 0, 0 };
std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << "(v == *cpi) : " << (v == *cpi)
    << "\ncpi : " << cpi;
```

Here is the output :

```
(v == *cpi) : true
cpi : [0,0,0]
```

And here is a test using `std::is_same_v`.

```cpp
tbx::cartesian_product_iterator cpi{ 2, 3, 2 };
std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << "std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>, decltype(*cpi)> : "
    << std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>, decltype(*cpi)>
    << "\ncpi : " << cpi;
```

```
std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>, decltype(*cpi)> : true
cpi : [0,0,0]
```

With these preliminaries, all we need to answer your question is a `dot_product` function. For that, the Standard Library has function `std::inner_product`. The values described in your original question are found by dotting the constant vector on the left (e.g., [0x100, 0x10, 0x1]) with each new Cartesian product from the `cartesian_product_iterator`. Looping until the iterator is exhausted gets them all.

Here is the demo program. It was developed with the latest version of MSVC. I have become addicted to the simplicity of `import std`, so I am posting the modules I used. I apologize, because you will have to work out which headers to include if you cannot use modules. Function `cartesian_products` returns the vector you requested in the original question.

I am pleased with how the code factored out in this program. All the functions are short and obvious. The same is true for class `cartesian_product_iterator` below. More than 90% of it is trivial. For these reasons, it *feels* like using `cartesian_product iterator` was the right approach.

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import std;
import tbx.cartesian_product_iterator;

int dot_product(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> const& b) {
    return std::inner_product(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin(), 0);
}
auto cartesian_products(std::vector<int> const v, tbx::cartesian_product_iterator cpi) {
    if (v.size() != cpi.size())
        throw std::invalid_argument("size mismatch in tbx::cartesian_products(v, cpi)");
    std::vector<int> c;
    for (; !cpi.is_at_end(); ++cpi)
        c.emplace_back(dot_product(v, *cpi));
    return c;
}
void put(std::string_view heading, int const width, std::vector<int> const& v) {
    std::cout << heading << '\n';
    for (auto const& vv : v)
        std::cout << std::format("{:#0{}x}\n", vv, width);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
export int main() {
    put("Example 1", 4, cartesian_products({ 0x10, 0x1 }, { 2, 4 }));
    put("Example 2", 5, cartesian_products({ 0x100, 0x10, 0x1 }, { 2, 3, 2 }));
    put("Example 3", 3, cartesian_products({ 0x1 }, { 5 }));
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.ixx
```

Here is the output :

```
Example 1
0x00
0x01
0x02
0x03
0x10
0x11
0x12
0x13

Example 2
0x000
0x001
0x010
0x011
0x020
0x021
0x100
0x101
0x110
0x111
0x120
0x121

Example 3
0x0
0x1
0x2
0x3
0x4
```

And, finally, we have the definition for `cartesian_product_iterator`. In addition to the constructor for `std::initializer_list`, it also has one for `std::vector<int>`. There is also a `reset` function, in case you need to iterate through the Cartesian products more than once, and a `size` function that returns the size of the vector returned by `operator*`.

All the fun happens in function `increment`, which is the helper for `operator++`. It is defined at the very end. The logic there is not too bad, once you figure out that it mimics "add-with-carry" or the operation of an odometer.

```cpp
// tbx.cartesian_product_iterator.ixx
export module tbx.cartesian_product_iterator;
import std;
export namespace tbx
{
    class cartesian_product_iterator
    {
        std::vector<int> max, v;
        bool at_end{ false };
    public:
        cartesian_product_iterator(std::initializer_list<int> max_plus_one)
            : max{ convert(max_plus_one) }
            , v(max.size(), 0)
            , at_end{ false }
        {}
        explicit cartesian_product_iterator(std::vector<int> const& max_plus_one)
            : max{ convert(max_plus_one) }
            , v(max.size(), 0)
            , at_end{ false }
        {}
        bool is_at_end() const {
            return at_end;
        }
        void reset() {
            for (auto& vv : v)
                vv = 0;
            at_end = false;
        }
        auto size() const {
            return v.size();
        }
        auto operator*() const
            -> std::vector<int>   // could return const& in some applications
        {
            if (at_end)
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    "cartesian_product_iterator cannot be dereferenced "
                    "when at its end.");
            return v;
        }
        auto& operator++() {
            increment();
            return *this;
        }
        auto operator++(int) {
            auto t{ *this };
            increment();
            return t;
        }
        friend auto operator<< (
            std::ostream& ost,
            cartesian_product_iterator const& cpi
            ) -> std::ostream&
        {
            ost.put('[');
            auto it{ cpi.v.cbegin() };
            if (it != cpi.v.cend())
                for (;;) {
                    ost << *it;
                    if (++it == cpi.v.cend())
                        break;
                    ost.put(',');
                }
            ost.put(']');
            return ost;
        }
    private:
        auto static convert(std::vector<int> max_plus_one)
            -> std::vector<int>
        {
            if (max_plus_one.empty())
                throw std::invalid_argument("max_plus_one cannot be empty");
            for (auto& max : max_plus_one)
                if (--max < 0)
                    throw std::invalid_argument("max_plus_one must hold positive values");
            return max_plus_one;
        }
        void increment()
        {
            if (at_end)
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    "cartesian_product_iterator cannot be incremented "
                    "beyond its end.");
            else if (v == max)
                at_end = true;
            else {
                // "odometer logic"
                for (auto i{ v.size() }; i--;)
                    if (v.at(i) == max.at(i))
                        v.at(i) = 0;
                    else {
                        ++v.at(i);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    };
}
// end file: tbx.cartesian_product_iterator.ixx
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `GetAllResults` do some check, which is not necessary if you can really ensure that(`stdr` is `std::ranges`; if you cannot use C++20, you may use  `std::any` with an iterator pair). We also assume that `maxTimes[i] * bitmasks[i]` will not overlap with each other(as your examples show).

```cpp
void GetAllResults_(const std::vector<unsigned int>& bitmasks,
    const std::vector<unsigned int>& maxTimes, unsigned int depth,
    unsigned int currVal, std::vector<unsigned int>& result)
{
    // assume: arr[i] == 0x0..1..0.
    unsigned int newDepth = depth + 1;
    if (newDepth == bitmasks.size())
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxTimes[depth]; i++)
            result.push_back(currVal + i * bitmasks[depth]);
        return;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxTimes[depth]; i++)
    {
        unsigned int newVal = currVal + i * bitmasks[depth];
        GetAllResults_(bitmasks, maxTimes, newDepth, newVal, result);
    }
    return;
}

std::vector<unsigned int> GetAllResults(const std::vector<unsigned int>& bitmasks,
    const std::vector<unsigned int>& maxTimes)
{
    if (bitmasks.size() != maxTimes.size() || bitmasks.empty() || maxTimes.empty())
        return {};
    if (stdr::any_of(maxTimes, [](unsigned int time) { return time > 0x10; }))
        return {};

    std::vector<unsigned int> result;
    GetAllResults_(bitmasks, maxTimes, 0, 0, result);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = GetAllResults({ 0x100,0x010, 0x001 }, { 2,3,2 });
    // output as you like
    return 0;
}
```